# Relying on TFS 2010 Notification Service

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2005, tfsbuild

I need to fire up a few workflows which are driven by the change in build quality. I can either write up a quick service that subscribes to the correct events in the TFS 2010 Notification model and write my workflows when these events are received or I can write a VS Add In which the users can use to trigger my workflows. I can not write a separate web based UI or anything that takes the users out of Visual Studio.

So my questions are
1. How reliable is TFS 2010 Notification Service? I have observed that there could be substantial delay (upto 4 minutes) at times before a listener (I have a test one running) gets invoked. Is there a way to speed this up to get near real time events?

1. Is there any other provision in TFS 2010 to be able to achieve what I need to other than the notification service route?
2. If I have to go down the VS add in route can someone please point me to the right set of resources? I have some idea on how to get this done actually. My issue is that this add in should load/work in VS2005, 2008 and 2010

Comment: Nikhil, please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed

Comment: John sorry I didn't quite get what you wanted me to see?

Comment: The fact that you shouldn't add a signature or tagline.

Comment: But I didn't add a signature or a tagline. Actually I am not even sure what a tagline is.

Comment: You had "Thanks for reading!"

Comment: Ahh OK. Sorry my bad then. Apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we decided to write our own subscription service to handle this scenario.